# How to get resource utilized by rethinkdb?

Tags: rethinkdb

Is there easy way to get information, like total database size, cache used and so on in rethinkdb?

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at system tables (stored in the `rethinkdb` database). They contain a lot of useful information about the database. In particular, you should take a look at [status tables](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/system-tables/#status-tables) and s[ystem stats](http://rethinkdb.com/docs/system-stats/).